# Mock two methods for the same function python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I want to mock two methods (predict_proba and classes_) of a [sklearn model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). I have a function that receives a template and text, and returns a label and a score.

```
import numpy as np
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def model_predict_proba(model, text):
    pred_proba_model = model.predict_proba([text])
    score = pred_proba_model.max()
    label = model.classes_[np.argmax(pred_proba_model)]
    return label, score


def test_model_predict_proba():
    mock_model = MagicMock()
    mock_model.predict_proba.return_value = np.array([0.90, 0.23])
    mock_model.classes_.return_value= np.array(['FOOD', 'DRINK'])
    text = 'Apple pie'

    expected = ("FOOD", 0.90)
    result = model_predict_proba(mock_model, text)
    
    assert result == expected
```

When I run this test, I get the following error message:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def model_predict_proba(model, text):
    pred_proba_model = model.predict_proba([text])
    score = pred_proba_model.max()
    label = model.classes_[np.argmax(pred_proba_model)]
    return label, score


def test_model_predict_proba():
    mock_model = MagicMock()
    mock_model.predict_proba.return_value.max.return_value = 0.90
    mock_model.classes_.__getitem__.return_value ='FOOD'
    text = 'Apple pie'

    expected = ("FOOD", 0.90)
    result = model_predict_proba(mock_model, text)

    assert result == expected
```

Note that since you're mocking your model, this test is not actually testing the model in any useful way -- I'm assuming you're writing this function just as an exercise to understand how `MagicMock` works.  The purpose of mocking is usually to simulate the inputs or dependencies of the thing you're testing, rather than the thing itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it solved my problem!

My goal in this test is not to test the model, but, given a model (already trained) and any text, the function has to return a label and a score to me.

Comment: Could you explain to me what these two steps mean? 

1) mock_model.predict_proba.return_value.max.return_value

2) mock_model.classes_.__getitem__.return_value

Comment: It's just setting up the return values of the mocks to produce the exact things that will make your test pass.  `mock_model.predict_proba.return_value.max` is the function that will be called in `model_predict_proba` to get the `score` (which you want to be `0.90`) and `mock_model.classes_.__getitem__` is called to get `label`.  Again, none of this is testing the actual model, it's just completely fake responses to make the test pass, which is why it's not a useful test.  (It's not possible to get "real" responses out of a mock -- it just returns the fake responses you give it.)